# Stop showing the CSS Outline window in Visual Studio when editing CSS files

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Whenever I navigate to a CSS file, the CSS Outline window appears - how do I stop it doing that, it's annoying!

Comment: The implementation of contextual windows on multiple monitor setups is garbage. I know quite a few devs who want to know an answer to this. Especially since VS is awful at managing windows as it is.

Answer (score 2):

I finally think I figured out a way of doing this:

1. Click on the small down arrow on the top right of this annoying window
2. Click on "hide".

[image]

Seems to work !

Comment: I have tried that, but next time I open up Visual Studio, it comes back again. I want to turn it off permanently!

Comment: I tried too, closed / opened visual studio again, open other files and the window is still hidden.